# Why is there an error when I run an exe file compiled from a python file in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, exe

I wanted to use pyradiomics to extract radiomic features from medical images in MATLAB, so I tried to transfer my FeatureExtraction file to an exe file, then call it in MATLAB. I used pyinstaller -F -w FeatureExtraction.py in command line, then I got an exe file FeatureExtraction.exe. But when I called the exe file in MATLAB, there was an error : pykwalify.errors.CoreError: <CoreError: error code 3: Provided source_file do not exists on disk :C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI318322\radiomics\schemas\paramSchema.yaml: Path: '/'>

I tried to run the FeatureExtraction.py in Pycharm, there was no error. I could get the result I wanted. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled some packages use in the file, there was still no error. But when I called the exe file compiled from the python file in MATLAB, there was still that error:
pykwalify.errors.CoreError: <CoreError: error code 3: Provided source_file do not exists on disk :C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI318322\radiomics\schemas\paramSchema.yaml: Path: '/'>

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you run the EXE from the command line, outside of MATLAB? If no, then this is not related to MATLAB, and you’ve narrowed down the problem a bit. If yes, then this is related to the MATLAB environment for running external programs, and you’ve narrowed down the problem a lot.